Внедрение браузера из Selenium в окно WPF. C#
Задача заключается в том, чтобы в окне приложения WPF у меня запускался браузер, который выполняет автотест с использованием фреймворка Selenium. Дело в том, что Selenium сам запускает браузер, а мне нужно, чтобы он действовал именно в моем WPF. Как это реализовать?

Чтобы работать в окне своём, не нужен селениум. Берёте CEF (Chrome) или WebView2 (Edge) и управляете встроенным браузером напрямую без селениума.

Спасибо, это реально то, что нужно. Однако в Selenium очень простые методы для управления, а тут, как я понимаю, нужно всё через JS делать?

Преимущественно JS, да.

Понял, большое спасибо.
